# How to modify the katalon Reports

Tags: selenium-webdriver, katalon

[image: Report]

I have generated a test suite and run the testng.xml file and default report is generated accordingly.

I want to modify default generated report. I want to display one column which shows the pass and fail result for each testcase. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After execution of test suite, In the particular project refer Reports folder. In that .csv file will be appear. It will have the test step, response time, test status. The reference screenshot is below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can modify the .csv file as Bhavani said above.

For your information, they also provide Katalon Analytics (beta version) - a web-based analytics platform with visual reports/ charts. The user guide could be found [here](http://dzone.com/articles/execute-automation-testing-in-3-steps)

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the template of the email that will be sent after a test suite is executed.
Project-Settings-Email-Template